# CSS magic to center text and img for fixed html

Tags: html, css, image, center, fixed

I have a piece of fixed html which is beyond my reach to change and I would like to style it to my liking, but I can't figure out how. This is what I have:

```
<a title="some title" href="...">
   <img src="....jpg"></img>
   Some text
</a>
```

CSS:

```
div.container-outer {
width: 25%;
float:left;
}
div.container-inner {
width: 156px;
margin: 5px;
}
div.container-inner img {
max-width: 156px;
max-height: 124px;
}
```

I would like the text centered under the img, and both text and img centered in a fixed width containing div. The width and height of the images are unknown, but there is a max-width and a max-height, and the max-width is smaller than the containing div. Also, the bottom of the picture should be at a fixed position inside the containing div.

I'm free to modify the html around this code snippet.

Is this even possible? I have bashed my head into the wall for the last hour and I'm still clueless....

Best Regards,
Markus

edit 130513 ------------------------------------------------

Added current CSS. This leaves me with the image left-aligned, and the text below also left aligned. If the image changes height then the bottom part of the image moves since it is top aligned.

Comment: Post your CSS or a jsFiddle link

Comment: you could try first setting a[title~=some title] img { text-align: center; or margin: 0 auto; or set them in display: block; } You need to give us an idea where you have started at.

Comment: problem is that if I do text-align: center and img {display:inline} then the text jumps up next to the image if the image width is small.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="..." alt="..." /><br />
    <span>text<span>
</div>
```

You can style the div's width in the style param itself. You need to BR after the img because img are inline objects like loose text (text not wrapped inside a P element or something.

The span is only there because you can later style it

Comment: I can't change the html block <a><img>text</img></a>, it is php output from code I can't access. I can only add html around it.

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't managed to do this in CSS... could you use Javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.container-inner {
            width: 156px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function addBr() {
            document.getElementById('container-inner').innerHTML = document.getElementById('container-inner').innerHTML.replace(/(<img.+?>)/, '$1<br>');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="addBr();">
    <div id="container-inner" class="container-inner">
        <a title="some title" href="...">
            <img src="images/sample.jpg">
            Some text
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo: http://doug.exploittheweb.com/SO/16521934.html

FWIW, `</img>` is not valid HTML and almost certainly won't be present in `.innerHTML` even if it's there in the source code.